# MS Access Two Masters - One Detail

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

There is very simple in MS Access to have Mater->Detail form, 
How is it possible to have a form with two masters tables and one child?

It could be for example tables: [Students], [Exams], [Questions]. [Questions] table has StudentID, and ExamID, I can show all questions of the student (but it includes all exams), or all questions of exam (but it includes all students).

How is it possible to show all questions of one student and his one exam?

Appreciate any help or point to any resource.

Thanks you!

ADDED:

```
[Students] {ID, Name}
[Exams] {ID, Number, Date}
[Questions] {ID, Question, Answer, Mark, ExamID, StudentID}
```

Comment: please describe user interface you want

Comment: one form, at the top left: [Students], at the top right [Exams] at the bottom [Questions]

Comment: Can you specify the relevant columns in each table--especially the relationships.

Comment: I just added tables structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create form [fMain] with no RecordSource.
Put sub forms [fStudents], [fExams] with it's table RecordSource. 
Put sub form [fQuestions] it's RecordSource should be

```
SELECT [Questions].* FROM [Questions] WHERE ([Questions].[ExamID] = Forms![fMain]![fExams].Form![ID]) AND ([Questions].[StudentID] = Forms![fMain]![fStudents].Form![ID])
```

Here Forms![fMain]![fStudents].Form![ID] means take value of [ID] from form in control named fStudents in form named [fMain].

In forms [fStudents], [fExams] Create onCurrent event with such code

```
on error resume next
Parent.fQuestion.Form.Requery
on error goto 0
```